# How to dynamically change the editor id in joomla?

Tags: tinymce, joomla3.0

I have a div with class "row" which includes a text field and a textarea.
For textarea I use the joomla `JFactory::getEditor();` .

With a button click using jquery this div is dynamically created. But the editor created is not editable. When the whole div is repeated editor id repeats.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem by using ajax. To dynamically create the div use ajax. We need not have to specify the id name of the editor but for my case, since its created dynamically we need to change the id name.

```
echo $editor->display( 'details[]', null, '400', '400', '20', '20', false, 'det_'.$this->id, null, null, $params ); //id is passed from ajax data.
```

Editor so generated will be editable and we can get the details as array on form post.